# Mimic React custom component

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom Reactjs component to display Pagination with next/previous buttons at the bottom of a grid. Now, the business needs to display the same component on top of the grid as well. How to display the previous /next button events based on the input provided in prev/next buttons at the bottom of the grid?

I tried using javascript `innerHTML` to mimic the behaviour. It works only with the display. It does not attach the event listener of the buttons. I tried even with

```
document.querySelector.addEventListener('click', ()=>{console.log('test')})
```

It does not work. Is there a better way to do with react.

Comment: Post that component code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put that component on top and bottom

```
<Grid>
 <Pagination />
 {...someOtherComponents}
 <Pagination />
</Grid>
```

- it's ok in react. Optimization that you want to do is overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to just add some more content to Shmili Breuer answer.

If i understood you correctly you have 2 navigations, one at the top one at the bottom. The way you connect them would be through a state of you component, or a parent component if you are using functional component to render pagination stuff. So if you change the state it will reflect on both of your navigations. Also you can use only one function here, by passing a parameter, im gonna copy a code from before mentioned answer.

```js
 // first create a function
    nextFunction = (condition) => {
       if(condition){
          this.setState(prevState=>({
            page: prevState.page-1
          }))
       } else {
        this.setState(prevState=>({
            page: prevState.page+1
          }))
       }
    }

    // then use it in your button
    
    <button onClick={() => this.nextFunction(some condition)}>Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In react you would add an onClick attribute to an element you want to handle a click on.

Something like this

```
// first create a function
nextFunction = () => {
   do next functionality....   
}

// then use it in your button

<button onClick={() => this.nextFunction()}>Next</button>
```

This way you can have both top and bottom pagination call the same function.
Hope this helps